# Python - How to return a the details of each Room instance in a list, from inside of a Map instance

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am working on a small text adventure in python, and am attempting to use classes.  I'm not very well versed in OOP and although I feel like I'm slowly gaining a greater understanding...I know that I still have a ways to go.

This is my room class

```
#!usr/bin/env python3

"""
A room class and a method to load room data from json files
"""




import json


class Room():
    def __init__(
        self,
        id = "0",
        name = "An empty room",
        desc = "There is nothing here",
        items = {},
        exits = {},
        ):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.items = items
        self.exits = exits
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(self.name, self.desc, self.items, self.exits)

    # Create method to verify exits
    def _exits(self, dir):
        if dir in self.exits:
            return self.exits[dir]
        else:
            return None

    def north(self):
        return self._exits('n')

    def south(self):
        return self._exits('s')

    def east(self):
        return self._exits('e')

    def west(self):
        return self._exits('w')

# Create method to get room info from json file
def get_room(id):
    ret = None
    with open("data/{}.json".format(str(id)) , "r") as f:
        jsontext = f.read()
        d = json.loads(jsontext, strict = False)
        d['id'] = id
        ret = Room(**d)
    return ret
```

This is my map class

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from rooms import *
"""
Map class used to build a map from all of the rooms
"""



class Map():

    def __init__(self, rooms = {}):
        self.rooms = rooms

    def __str__(self):
        return map(str, rooms)







def build_map(id, num_of_rooms):
    rooms = {}
    room_count = 0
    while room_count < num_of_rooms:
        rooms[id] = get_room(id)
        id += 1
        room_count += 1
    return rooms

a_map = Map(build_map(1, 3))

def test_map(map):
    return map.rooms

print(test_map(a_map))
```

I'm not understanding why test_map only returns a list of objects, and was wondering how I might be able to receive the actual list of rooms so that I can confirm that they were created properly.  I'm sure that I'm just going about this the COMPLETE wrong way...which is why I've come here with the issue.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is specifically wrong with this?  I thought I worded it well enough and provided a decent example.  In response to rejecting the edit, I read multiple sources regarding multi-line arguments and this was just the format I decided I liked the most.

Comment: It would have been a bit better if you included more detail about what you get and what you're expecting. The section on including a "minimum, complete, verifiable example" is probably most relevant.

As for the formatting - hey, it's your code! but I've never seen multi-line arguments indented to the same level as the function body, and it struck me as very hard to read. In fact, the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) explicitly recommends against it.

Comment: I also often like the one-argument-per-line style, but I indent it either one level deeper than the function body or directly below the open paren.

Comment: Ah...I understand.  I didn't clarify the actual output I was receiving.  I'll also edit the code to follow PEP8.  Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general information about `__str__` and `__repr__`, Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/9200529).

In this case, here's what's happening:

- Your `__str__` function on `Map` doesn't return a string, it returns a `map` object. `__str__` *must* return a string.
- That's not causing an error because the function isn't getting called, here: `test_map` returns the given `Map`'s `rooms` attribute, which is a dictionary. If you tried to do `print(a_map)` you'd get an exception.
- Dictionaries have their own `__str__` method, which *is* getting called here but the dictionary's `__str__` method calls `__repr__` on its members, which you haven't defined. (See the linked answer for details on why this is so.)
- When you haven't defined a `__repr__` for your class, you get the `__repr__` from `object`, which is why your `print(test_map(a_map))` gives you output like `{1: <__main__.Room instance at 0x7fca06a5b6c8>, 2: <__main__.Room instance at 0x7fca06ac3098>, 3: <__main__.Room instance at 0x7fca06ac36c8>}`.

What I'd suggest:

- Write `__repr__` functions for both `Map` and `Room`.
- Have `Map.__repr__` return a string that indirectly relies on `Room.__repr__`, something like the following:

  `def __repr__(self):
      return '<Map: {}>'.format(self.rooms)`

This isn't maybe the best long-term approach - what if you have a map with a hundred rooms? - but it should get you going and you can experiment with what works best for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for.
Not sure what I was thinking with the __str__ method in the Map class, but thank you for clearing that up as well.

But then, in which way would I actually call this to print so that I can see it?  Would the function under my map class work to call it?  I still don't think I fully comprehend.

I actually looked over my map class and I remember what I was attempting to do in the str method.  I was trying to map the list to a string.

Comment: You know, I think I may have misled you on this one. I'm going to edit my response a bit.

Comment: Well, instead I rewrote it completely :-D Hope it's more useful now.